# A 'Soduku' like game but instead focused on maximizing the sum in a box.

Tags: optimization, puzzle, maxima-minima

Goal: Maximize the sum of all the numbers in the box.

Rules:

I. Every square has to contain a single number.

II. Only the numbers from 1 through to 4 can be used.

III.

- 1 can be placed anywhere.
- 2 must be placed next to 1.
- 3 must be placed next to 1 AND 2.
- 4 must be placed next to 1 AND 2 AND 3.
  "Next to" in this context means horizontally OR vertically. **Not diagonally.**

IV. The box must be a perfect square box.
[image: Equal in width as well as height.]

Example of max sum in this 3x3 box. Max sum is 20
[image: 3x3 box]

Question One:
I want to find a formula that when given the dimensions, gives the maximum sum as output.
example: f(3)=/unknown/=20

Question Two:
How would one arrange the numbers in such a way to achieve the maximal sum, **without** running it through a computer simulation

Where I am completely stuck:

- How to express mathematically that a number can share with another number. For example, in the 3x3 box, both 4's share the same 3.
  Thus reducing the need to add another 3 to create a 4.

My approach thus far: For the 3x3 box
4x+3y+2z+1w= Max.
9<Max<36 (The lowest if the squares are filled with 1's, highest if it is filled with 4's)
From the rules you quickly realize you cannot have 4's without at least one of the other numbers. The higher inequality is thus reduced. For the lower inequality, you can easily see that 1's can fill the middle vertical row, and thus allowing for 2's on the sides.
The new interval is thus 15<Max<30

Constraints:
x+y+z+w=9 (The total amount of squares)

Comment: A lower bound you can make is that for any box of dimension $n=a^2$ you can just fill with $n$ of the boxes of size $a$, so you have $f(n) \geq nf(a)$. This gives for example $f(9) \geq 180$. Also, it would be nice to know if this problem has any context or not.

Comment: @AniCh Very interesting! How did you come to that conclusion? (Anywhere I can read about this?) This is an alteration on a question I read but no answer was given. And contained many unnecessary details. This is the "distilled" version.

Comment: It's just realizing that the global restriction is softer than the local ones. Which means if we put two boxes that follow your restriction together, the joint box will also follow the restriction, that's why writing $9$ boxes of your particular $3\times 3$ example will be a possibility for the $9\times 9$ box. This problem doesn't remind me of anything I've seen before, so I can't offer you any reference about it. My approach would be start with an algorithm and try to watch for patterns.

Comment: For an upper limit I tried to fill an infinite grid with numbers following your rules. I am not sure If I got something like this. Fill every square with 1. Then fill as many 2s as you can. This should lead to a pattern that has a sequence like 1-2-2 which repeats itself on each row and column, with a shift from one row or column to the next one. Then you would get clusters of 2 by 2 boxes, each containing the value 2. These clusters can be refilled (not sure if optimally, but I could not find a better solution) with a pattern like 4-3/2-3, where 4-3 is on the first row, and 2-3 on the second.

Comment: Since the pattern repeats itself, you can cut a finite n by n block and get an upper limit of your function, since the sum of the numbers that remain after the cut will be  greater than what you can get by taking into account the border of the finite grid. Maybe this helps.

Comment: In theoretical optimal density, every instance of 1 would support four instances in {2,3,4},  every instance of 2 would support three instances in {3,4},  every instance of 3 would support two instances in {4}. This gives an upper bound of $\frac{14}{5}n^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot compute $f(n)$ exactly yet, but I can prove that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)/n^2=14/5
$$
Here's why. Every square labeled $2,3$ or $4$ needs to be next to a square labeled $1$. Furthermore, each $1$ can only satisfy four squares numbered $2,3$ or $4$. Therefore, at least one out of five squares must be labeled $1$.

Similarly, of the squares labeled $2,3,4$, at least $1/4$ of them must be labeled $2$, because a $2$ can only satisfy three squares labeled $3$ or $4$. And of the remaining squares labeled $3$ or $4$, at least $1/3$ must be labeled $3$. This means that
$$
f(n)/n^2\le \frac15\cdot1 +\frac14\cdot \frac45\cdot2+\frac45\cdot \frac34\cdot \frac13\cdot 3+(1-\frac15-\frac14\cdot \frac45-\frac45\cdot \frac34\cdot \frac13)\cdot 4 =\frac{14}5
$$
On the other hand, we can acheive a sum which is close to $\frac{14}5n^2$ using this pattern. Namely, there is a single tile of area $5$, in the shape of a "$P$" pentomino, which tessellates the plane, where all tiles are labeled the same way.

[image]

In each block of $5$, there is a sum of $4+4+3+2+1=14$, achieving the  claimed density of $14/5$. Now, there is a slight problem that these blocks of area five cannot exactly fill an $n\times n$ square. To fix this, first cover the entire $n\times n$ square with the tiling, allowing some tiles to go outside the box. Here is the result when $n=6$.

[image]

Note that some of the tiles do not have their requirements satisfied, since the numbers which satisfy them are outside of the $n\times n$ box. These are labeled in red. Here is one way to fix this:

> For every pair of adjacent $4$'s on the border, replace them with a $1$ and $2$, such that the $2$ is next to an unsatisfied $3$ on the border if it exists. For every isolated $4$ on the border, replace it with a $2$.

The fact that the tiling does not quite fit, and these replacements, make a reduction in the total sum which is negligible compared to $\frac{14}5n^2$.

---

In order to compute $f(n)$ exactly, you would need a much more precise analysis, where you consider the number of $1$'s in the interior and on the border separately, and same for the other numbers.

Comment: In your $n=6$ illustration, better not to use a $6\times7$ box, even though conceptually it is OK. The limit case of course looks good.

Comment: @Macavity Haha, good catch! Since it gets the idea across, I think it is not worth fixing.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Blown away by this answer! I will gladly accept it! One question, do you what area of math you can find this type of question? I would love to practice more question similar to this in nature but I have been unable to find such questions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Second question after a bit of pondering, how did you know that "sharing" numbers wouldn't be a problem? See for example my 3x3 box example. The 4's share a single 3.

Comment: The narrowest area of math I can think of describing this problem is "combinatorics," which is not too helpful for finding similar questions. Here is a similar problem I've seen on reddit: you have an $n\times n$ grid colored red green and blue, so each red square neighbors a green square, each green square neighbors a blue square, and each blue square neighbors a red square. Prove the number of red squares is at least $n^2/11$, and at most $\tfrac23 n^2$.

Comment: @MatJour I have accounted for sharing. The point is that at no more than two $4$'s can share a $3$, since the $3$ needs to also be adjacent to a $2$ and $1$. This means that at least $1/3$ of the $3'$ and $4$'s must be $3$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest My apologize you are right. And thank you for the question, look very much forward to working on it!

Comment: In the optimal exact solutions for $n=4$, I can see an instance of a tile similar to yours, but some squares are swapped (permuted) to allow higher values on the outer (border) squares. For instance, a tile like yours but $1$ and $3$ are swapped, works better than your current tile for $n=4$. ([Here are all 6 solutions for optimal $f(4)=38$, up to symmetry.](https://pastebin.com/Nu0XGaEz)). I wonder if it is always possible to attain exact optimal $f(n)$ by using some permutation of your tile, followed by replacing "red" values (and nearby necessary values) on the outer (border) squares.